# Failed to store cell in cache

Tags: caching, symfony5, phpspreadsheet

I am using multiple csv files to populate the tables in a database.
As I am on Symfony, I created a command which from a given directory read files in a defined order.

A csv file equals a table in my BD.

File sizes differ from file to file and may contain over than 65 thousand lines.

My script has been running locally for 3 days, it's progressing but it's heavy.

On a recipe server my script stops just after a few minutes showing this error:

> CRITICAL: Error thrown while running command "symfony-command-name". Message: "Failed to store cell BB18118 in cache" {"exception": "[object] (PhpOffice \ PhpSpreadsheet \ Exception (code: 0): Failed to store cell BB18118 in cache at project / vendor / phpoffice / phpspreadsheet / src / PhpSpreadsheet / Collection / Cells.php: 393)

I m using Symfony FileSystemAdapter, SimpleCacheBridge (1.1)

In My Symfony command I do:

```php
$pool = new FilesystemAdapter();
$simpleCache = new SimpleCacheBridge($pool);
Settings::setCache($simpleCache); // PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Settings

// loop directories and call Symfony service ...
```

In Symfony Service:

```php
$spreadSheet = IOFactory::load($csvPath);
$sheet = $spreadSheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray();
                
// loop sheet and databases operations ...
```

#### Stack

PHP : 7.4
SF : 5.3.9
phpspreadsheet : 1.18
SimpleCache : 1.1*

Any Help please

Answer (score 0):

I got the symfony cache working like this:

```
composer require symfony/cache
```

Code

```php
use Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\FilesystemAdapter;
use Symfony\Component\Cache\Psr16Cache;

$cache = new FilesystemAdapter();
$psr16Cache = new Psr16Cache($cache);
Settings::setCache($psr16Cache);
```

Anyway, it did not solve my memory issue.